# How do we insert images from Google Drive to spreadsheet cells?

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive, images, import

How do we insert images from Google Drive to spreadsheet cells?

Answer (score 2):

Detailed instructions are [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/97447?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en), from which the basics are:

> **Add an image**
>
> - Open a document, spreadsheet, or presentation in Google Docs, Sheets, or Slides.
> - Click Insert and then Image.
> - Select from the following options:
>
>   - Upload: Choose an image from your computer and click Open.
>   - Take a snapshot: Use your webcam and click Take a snapshot.
>   - By URL: Paste the URL of an image from the web and click Select.
>   - Your albums: Choose an image from one of your photos albums stored on the web and click Select.
>   - Google Drive: Choose an image stored in Google Drive and click Select.
>   - Search: Choose an image from the stock photography archive, or the Google and Life archives, and click Select.
>       Your image will be added to your file.
>
> **Image size and format requirements**
>
> Images must be less than 50 MB and be one of the following file types:
>
> .gif
>   .jpg
>   .png

There is also a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6WFdT2SX7QU).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, @pnuts method does *not* insert an image into a cell in a Google Sheet. It places the image in a layer above the cells, where it's not connected to any particular cell. You can move it around, size it, and so on, but it won't move when you sort or insert cells.

If you want the ***contents*** of a cell to be an image, you must use the `IMAGE()` function, which takes a URL as its main parameter, with optional parameters for resizing the image.

Sadly, the URL cannot point to an image on your Google Drive: it has to be a publicly available image with a plain-vanilla ***http://…*** type URL.
If there's an error in your URL parameter, you won't get an error message, and the function is tricky: an image URL that works fine with the HYPERLINK function may not work with `IMAGE`. You may also find image orientation changes for no obvious reason.